# Cannot access instance variable

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I have a problem I cant access the `mGirlsLisl` variable.
I think is a problem in the try catch.

The code works well but `onCreate` method cant access `mGirlsList` variable.
Please check the code
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ArrayList<Girl> mGirlsList;
private GirlClient girlClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    fetchGirls("girls.json");
    Log.i("LOG", String.valueOf(mGirlsList.size())); // ERROR can't get size
}

private void fetchGirls(String query) {

    girlClient = new GirlClient();
    String url = girlClient.getApiUrl(query);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
    Call call = client.newCall(request);

    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            String jsonData = response.body().string();
            try {
                mGirlsList = girlClient.getGirlsListFromJson(jsonData);

                Log.i("LOG", String.valueOf(mGirlsList.size())); // 5 OK
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the error that you get when trying to access it? NullPointerException?

Comment: method `onResponse()` of `Callback` will be run asynchronously after getting response from server. In `fetchGirls` you created class `Callback` but not call `onResponse`. So `mGirlsList` not initialized yet

Comment: @ShamasS   yes its a   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Suzy21  i posted the answer couple of days back. If it fixed the issue please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well you havent initialized the `mGirlsList` instance variable anywhere but tried to access the size inside the `OnCreate` method. Unlike thatt in the `OnResponse` method where you do a `mGirlsList = girlClient.getGirlsListFromJson(jsonData);`.

So make sure that you initialize the `mGirlsList` somewhere inside the `OnCreate` method.